# Deciding whether a non-f.g. non-divisible flat module is projective or not.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, projective-module, flatness

Assume $S= R[T]/(f)= R[w]$ is a flat non-divisible $R$-module, where $R$ is a noetherian UFD, $T$ is an indeterminate over $R$, and $f\in R[T]$ is a non-monic polynomial of positive degree.

Can we say if $S$ is $R$-projective or not?

I guess there is not enough information to answer this question. If so, is there an additional condition which guarantees the projectivity of $S$ as an $R$-module?

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377216/non-finitely-generated-non-projective-flat-module-over-a-polynomial-ring) is somewhat relevant. I have now posted this question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/214913/deciding-whether-a-non-f-g-non-divisible-flat-module-is-projective-or-not) also (willing to delete one of them).